# Sending data through post Handler resulting in "Cannot set headers"

Tags: node.js

my route handler sends an error when data is sent on the server, and this error emitted not always. I have started learning node.js,  my code of post route handler is posted under. I  have read more similar problems on StackOverflow and git and there is not a suitable solution.

**app/js**

```
app.post("/sendJson", function (request, response) {
  var jsonText = request.body.jsonList;

  var arrayJson = JSON.parse(jsonText);

  var accessToken = request.body.accessToken;
  var description = request.body.description;
  var deleteOptions = 0;
  if (checkTokenExist(request.body.accessToken)) {
    if (checkTokenExp(request.body.accessToken)) {
      con.query(
        "SELECT id_individual FROM user_token_individual WHERE user_access_token = ? ",
        [accessToken],
        function (err, resIdClient) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("error get id_individual " + err);
          } else {
            console.log("get id_individual " + resIdClient[0].id_individual);
            con.query(
              "INSERT INTO order_list_save(id_client,description,delete_options)VALUES(?,?,?)",
              [resIdClient[0].id_individual, description, deleteOptions],
              function (err, resInsertOrder) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log("error insert new value " + err);
                } else {
                  console.log("log insertId " + resInsertOrder.insertId);
                  var nowData = new Date();
                  arrayJson.forEach((element) => {
                    // console.log("element = " + element.service_id);
                    con.query(
                      "INSERT INTO order_table_save(data_order_save,id_order,quantity,price_number,id_service,service_name,service_unit,service_price_0,service_price_1,service_price_2,delete_options) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
                      [
                        nowData,
                        resInsertOrder.insertId,
                        element.quantity,
                        element.price_number,
                        element.id_service,
                        element.service_name,
                        element.service_unit,
                        element.service_price_0,
                        element.service_price_1,
                        element.service_price_2,
                        0,
                      ],
                      function (err, res) {
                        if (err) {
                          console.log(err);
                        } else {
                          response.json({
                            STATUS_CODES: 200,
                          });
                          response.end();
                        }
                      }
                    );
                  });
                }
              }
            );
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      response.json({
        STATUS_CODES: 401,
      });
      response.end();
    }
  } else {
    response.json({
      STATUS_CODES: 403,
    });
    response.end();
  }
});
```

my exception is "_http_outgoing" though I didn't use HTTP.

```
_http_outgoing.js:518
    throw new ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT('set');
    ^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:518:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/odmin/Документы/project node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/odmin/Документы/project node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/odmin/Документы/project node/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
    at Query.onResult (/home/odmin/Документы/project node/serverWork.js:442:36)
    at /home/odmin/Документы/project node/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/query.js:74:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: thats what called to good old callback hell, try to use promises and async awiat, but yes it would not solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

The error **" Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."** means that you're already in the Body or Finished state, but some function tried to set a header or statusCode. When you see this error, try to look for anything that tries to send a header after some of the body has already been written. For example, look for callbacks that are accidentally called twice, or any error that happens after the body is sent.

Replace this in your code

```
response.json({
        STATUS_CODES: 401,
      });
      response.end();
```

to this

```
res.status(200).send('some text');
```

Comment: i want to replace my code but i cant do this because i send status code on json on my android app where i cant to process res.status